# Queuing ObservableCollection Updates

Tags: c#, message-queue, observablecollection, state-machine

I am programming a TAPI application which uses the state pattern for dealing with the different states a TK can be in. Incoming and outgoing calls are recorded via an `ObservableCollection` in a `ListView` (call journal). The call data gets compared with contacts stored in a SQL-Server database to determine possible matches. That information is then used to update the call journal. All this in real time of course and all governed by/in the different states of the FSM (finite state machine).

To distinguish calls, I do use a call ID (which is provided by TAPI). When the phone rings or I start calling out, a new record including its call ID are added to the call journal and the customer database is searched for the number and certain data in the journal is updated accordingly. When proceeding through the different call states the application dynamically updates the journal (i.e. changing an icon that visually shows the state of the specific call, etc).

Exactly those updates to the `ObservableCollection` are giving me headaches, as they need to happen in a certain order. For example, when receiving a call the associated state will create a new entry in the `ObservableCollection`. When the state changes the new state might try to update the collection even though it is not clear weather the entry that is to be changed has been added already. The states happen to switch really fast, apparently faster than updating the collection can happen.

Would some kind of message queue be a possible/good solution? If so, how could such a message queue be implemented - in the context of either a state machine or an `ObservableCollection`. I am not looking for complete solutions, but any information which I cannot easily find via google or stackoverflow would be appreciated.

**Edit**: greatly rephrased the question.

**Edit**: I added my own solution for the problem, but will wait and see if there is possibly someone with a better idea.

Comment: BTW, you need to add `break` to your `foreach` to make it equivalent to `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Oh of course, thanks. Edited my post to reflect that info. Although it does not change the outcome in this special context.

Comment: Rephrased the question to make the main problem clearer (since its a bit clearer to me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked whether the result of `FirstOrDefault` is `null`? This can happen if no element with given `id` exists in the collection.

For example:

```
var element = this.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id);
if (element != null) {
    // Do something with element.Number.
}
```

Or you could just call `First` and see if you get `InvalidOperationException`.

**--- EDIT ---**

I see from your comment that you seem to be accessing the same `ObservableCollection` from multiple threads concurrently. If that is the case, you need to protect the shared data structure through locking. It is entirely possible that one thread begins inserting a new element just at the moment the other one is searching for it, leading to all sorts of undefined behavior. According to [MSN documentation for ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx):

*"Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."*

As for debugging, you can "freeze" other threads and so you can concentrate only on the thread of interest without excessive "jumping". See the Threads panel, right-click menu, Freeze and Thaw options.

Comment: The application actually never gets that far, the exception is thrown on the first line of your example (well, exactly on the LINQ query). As I mentioned, `this` is an ObservableCollection - of a custom class. Could it be that if some member of that class is null `FirstOrDefault` will throw that NullReferenceException (even if it is NOT the ID property)? Guess I will need to write a small test app to see if that is the case.

Comment: @SaschaHennig You should be able to set a breakpoint directly in the delegate (`p => p.ID == id`). It will be hit for every element of the collection, but you'll eventually reach the one with the problem and hopefully be able to diagnose it.

Comment: The reason I had trouble debugging was that the application is heavily threaded and jumping between threads - which also is the reason the value in the call journal is not updated before another thread is trying to validate it. Should have made the threading issue clearer in my first post. Nevertheless +1 as without your posts I would probably not gotten as far in the problem solving process as I am now. I think I will implement some kind of queue that updates the call journal.

Comment: Although I did not use this (much simpler and therefore better) approach at that time, as I liked the idea of implementing the command pattern a lot, this is actually a great and valid answer. The command pattern is practically just a more complex way of, well not really locking, but blocking thread execution (regarding my implementation). I should definitely have marked this answer a lot earlier. I am still quite happy to have gone my own way at that time, as I learned a lot, that does not change the above mentioned facts. So better late than never. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Updating the `ObservableCollection` is a long running process, at least compared to receiving and handling the TAPI-events. This can lead to race conditions, where a call state which would have to edit a call entry could not find the entry as it aquired the lock to writing/updating the collection prior to the call state that would actually have to add the call. Also, not handling the TAPI-events in the proper order would break the state machine.

I decided to implement a simplified [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). The TAPI-Events, who used to trigger the performance heavy state transactions, get added to a thread safe, non-blocking and observable command queue. When a command gets enqueued the queue class starts "executing" (and dequeuing) the commands in a new thread, that is it is triggering the proper call states in the finite state machine, until there are no commands left in the queue. If there is a dequeuing thread already running no new thread is created (multi-threading would lead to race conditions again) and the queue class is blocking reentrancy to make sure that only one command will ever be executed at the any one time.

So basically: all TAPI-events (the **invoker**) are added to a queue (the **client**) in the order they are happening, as fast as possible. The queue then relays the TAPI information to the **receiver**, the finite state machine performing the business logic, taking its time but making sure the information gets updated in the proper order.

**Edit:** Starting from .NET 4.0 you can use the [ConcurrentQueue(T) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) to achieve the same result.